# How can you filter out data based on their id?

Tags: reactjs, filter, element

So i kinda have to filter out my username from the given data so that you'll find the username that matches with the post but i don't really understand the role of the "*[0]*". Can anybody expain for me? Thank you so much!

This is my js:

```
<span className="postUsername">
    {Users.filter((u) => u.id === post?.userId)[0].username}
</span>
```

This is my data:

```
export const Users = [{
    id: 1,
    profilePicture: "assets/person/1.jpeg",
    username: "Safak Kocaoglu",
}
...

export const Posts = [{
    id: 1,
    desc: "Love For All, Hatred For None.",
    photo: "assets/post/1.jpeg",
    date: "5 mins ago",
    userId: 1,
    like: 32,
    comment: 9,
}
...
```

Comment: For `[0]` you pick the first item in the list.

Comment: `filter` returns an array and you are picking the first one with `[0]`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in that case you are expecting to get a single user and show the username which is the post userId. Filter will return you an array of the user matching the condition we gave. For the array here you are picking first element of that array with [0]. Here we want to have a single user so best way is to use find(), this will give us a single result.

If you want to have the username of the specific user (post.userId), the code will be like this:

```
{Users.find(u=> u.id === post?.userId).username}
```

So, filter() function is used for getting array result of matching condition and here with [0] you are picking the first element of the array. Instead of that if you use find() function you will get a single object.